# php find wrong json element

Tags: php, json

I have a string in json form which I decode to a php variable.
But if the json is not a valid json string, the decode gives a NULL.

I'm looking for a script which can tell me, on which part the decode will fail.

For example I have the following string:

`{
    "error": "OK",
    "pathlist": [
        {
            "path": "datu5"
            "pathId": "10100010"
        },
        {
            "path": "datum",
            "pathId": "10100011"
        }
    ]
}`

Then I want to show that the error is an error near line 4:
For example:

`Error: Parse error on line 4:
... "path" : "datu5"  "pathId" : "10100010
----------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ':', ',', ']', got 'STRING'`

I there such a php script?

Comment: You forgot coma `"path": "datu5",
            "pathId": "10100010"` batwan datu5 and pathId

Comment: Naumov, 
I know, this is an example of a wrong json.

Comment: sorry I don't finish understand

Answer (score 1):

Try this lib: https://github.com/Seldaek/jsonlint

#### Usage

```
use Seld\JsonLint\JsonParser;

$parser = new JsonParser();

// returns null if it's valid json, or a ParsingException object.
$parser->lint($json);

// Call getMessage() on the exception object to get
// a well formatted error message error like this

// Parse error on line 2:
// ... "key": "value"    "numbers": [1, 2, 3]
// ----------------------^
// Expected one of: 'EOF', '}', ':', ',', ']'

// Call getDetails() on the exception to get more info.

// returns parsed json, like json_decode() does, but slower, throws
// exceptions on failure.
$parser->parse($json);
```